# XSL Looping : <xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, loops, xslt

```
            <Array>
                   <A>80361785</A>
                   <A>00001159</A>                 
                   <A>80361785-1</A>
                   <A>00001159-1</A>
                   <Checkbox>true</Checkbox>
                   <Checkbox>false</Checkbox>
                   <Checkbox>true</Checkbox>
                   <Checkbox>false</Checkbox>
                   ..........................
            </Array>
```

Here, in this I need to loop tag A and tag Checkbox using xsl:for-each
[]-- checkbox
the

tried below code it prints all the elements under Array node including the checkbox tags

```
                     xsl:for-each select="$Array/A"
                        input type="checkbox"
                             xsl:value-of select="."                                    
                        /input>
                    /xsl:for-each
```

sorry cant paste my expected output stackflow doesnt allow me to attach any image..but it should be like ... 
                             whatever comes in A tag ... it should be displayed on screen and just in front of it .. a checkbox should be displayed,
                             which is coming in "checkbox" tag. 
                             Roughly drawing the output
                             [tick mark - means checked]80361785 []0001159 [tick mark - means checked]80361785-1 []0001159-1

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post your expected output **as code** and explain what the difficulty is.

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="$Array/A">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                     <xsl:value-of select="." />                 
                                </input>
               </xsl:for-each> sorry cant paste my expected output .. it should be like ... whatever comes in A tag ... it should be displayed on screen and just in front of it .. a  checkbox should be displayed which is "checkbox" tag.   Roughly drawing the output []80361785 []0001159 []80361785-1 []0001159-1

Comment: so for first tag A which is 80361785 , the first checkbox is true ..so it should be checked... but the problem I am facing here is .. cannot loop the checkbox values against the A tags.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

you may select the right Checkbox tag using the position() xpath. To compare the position of tag A and to select the Checkbox with this position use a variable.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Array/A">
  <input type="checkbox">
    <xsl:variable name="positionA" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:if test="../Checkbox[position()=$positionA][text()='true']">
      <xsl:attribute name="checked">true</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </input>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If you can change the input format do it. It is not very XML like to group elements by there position. Add Id or group A and Checkbox in one tag.

best regards
Mario